# Rotating an image in PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

I have lots of pdf files, each embedded with multiple images that need to be rotated.

I know I can extract the image out, rotate it and then again reconstruct the pdf, but is there any way that I can add a PDF command so that images rotate in place ?

Ideally, a PDF-library in python that will allow me to do that.

Edit:

One important detail I would like to add is that each page can have multiple images and each image needs to be rotated at a different angles. Think a task of straightening the images in a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question,

```
    import PyPDF2

    pdf_in = open('original.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for pagenum in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(pagenum)
        page.rotateClockwise(180)#Angle in degrees
        pdf_writer.addPage(page)

    pdf_out = open('rotated.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
    pdf_out.close()
    pdf_in.close()
```

Hope so, this solved your problem